# Having a base object that Interacts with copies in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For Illustrator, is there a easy way to have copies of an object reference back to the original? For example, if I changed the color of the original then all the copies' color will change also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the symbols palette to create a new symbol and then place instances of it. If you just want color to update you could also use a global color swatch — anything with that color will update whenever you change the color swatch.

Comment: Good point about the global color swatch, that's not in the duplicate thread.